# SIGSEGV when getting backtrace in a signal hanlder after invalid function call

Tags: c++, c, linux, boost-stacktrace

I'm trying to write a SIGSEGV/SIGABRT handler for my C++ program, but it doesn't seem to be able to properly unwind the stack when the segfault is due calling a function at an invalid address. Here's my test program:

```cpp
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <signal.h>

void signal_handler(int signum)
{
    if(signum == SIGSEGV) {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "before\n", 7);
        boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to(STDOUT_FILENO);
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "after\n", 6);
    }
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sa={0};
    sa.sa_handler = signal_handler;
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, nullptr); 

    auto fp = reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(0x55);
    fp();
}
```

When I run it (`g++ test.cpp  && ./a.out`), it prints before and not after (and no binary stack data). Running it in a debugger gives some insight as well:

```cpp
lldb a.out
(lldb) target create "a.out"
Current executable set to '/home/russell/teststack/a.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) r
Process 88677 launched: '/home/russell/teststack/a.out' (x86_64)
Process 88677 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x55)
    frame #0: 0x0000000000000055
error: memory read failed for 0x0
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x55)
  * frame #0: 0x0000000000000055
    frame #1: 0x0000555555555247 a.out`main + 108
    frame #2: 0x00007ffff7829290 libc.so.6`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3123 + 128
    frame #3: 0x00007ffff782934a libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 138
    frame #4: 0x00005555555550a5 a.out`_start at start.S:115
(lldb) c
Process 88677 resuming
before
Process 88677 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x55)
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e8d72e libgcc_s.so.1`uw_frame_state_for at md-unwind-support.h:63:6
(lldb) bt
* thread #1, name = 'a.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x55)
  * frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e8d72e libgcc_s.so.1`uw_frame_state_for at md-unwind-support.h:63:6
    frame #1: 0x00007ffff7e8f4ab libgcc_s.so.1`_Unwind_Backtrace at unwind.inc:303:14
    frame #2: 0x00005555555553de a.out`boost::stacktrace::detail::this_thread_frames::collect(void const**, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 122
    frame #3: 0x0000555555555499 a.out`unsigned long boost::stacktrace::detail::this_thread_frames::safe_dump_to_impl<int>(int, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 106
    frame #4: 0x00005555555551be a.out`signal_handler(int) + 69
    frame #5: 0x00007ffff783e8e0 libc.so.6`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3219 + 1
    frame #6: 0x0000000000000055
    frame #7: 0x0000555555555247 a.out`main + 108
    frame #8: 0x00007ffff7829290 libc.so.6`___lldb_unnamed_symbol3123 + 128
    frame #9: 0x00007ffff782934a libc.so.6`__libc_start_main + 138
    frame #10: 0x00005555555550a5 a.out`_start at start.S:115
```

I get much the same result on aarch64 (except it raises SIGBUS instead of SIGSEGV).

Is there any way to get a backtrace when the top frame is invalid?

Comment: Accessing invalid addresses is undefined behaviour, be it variables or functions – you cannot expect *any* specific behaviour from there on onwards...

Comment: And once SIGSEGV occurs, in general, undefined behavior has already occured. Stuff like `write()`, in the signal handler, is probably ok. Anything else, especially anything that might begin with "boost", will not end well.

Comment: safe_dump_to is explicitly marked as Async-Handler-Safe https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/doc/html/boost/stacktrace/safe_dump_1_3_36_7_6_2_1_5.html

Comment: Oh intersting, libunwind does not seem to have this problem

Comment: @RussellGreene: The doc is contradictory -- the first part says it only works *if* it is async safe, implying you can't call it from a non-async-safe context.  But the implementation clearly can't deal with an invalid address on the stack.